# Docker-compose pulls an two images, an app and fluentd but no logs are sent to stdout for fluentd

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, fluentd

I'm new fluentd and I'm using two docker images one image is fluentd and my other image is my webapp. The webapp is creating logs and fluentd is listening on a port with the in_forward type but logs are not being sent to stdout

Docker-compose.yml file

```
  dataporter:
    image: <app-docker>
    command: <associated command>
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    links:
      - fluentd
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: :24224
        tag: data-porter

  fluentd:
    image: <fluentd-docker>
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd.conf:/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
```

fluentd.conf file

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind "0.0.0.0"
</source>

<match **>
   @type stdout
</match>
```

My app is in golang and I put some simple log statements with this package `import log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"` and so my simple log statements are `log.Info("Infof print")` but no new logs are shown in fluentd docker container logs besides the initial start up statements.

Comment: I created a minimal setup to try to reproduce this - a go app using logrus in one container, fluentd in another - and got log output with no problem. Please read about how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem and update your question.

Comment: I found the issue here. Even using a `depends_on` or `links` the `dataporter` container doesn't wait for `fluentd` to finish running. Simply stop `dataporter` container and composing the docker image again fixes it. Not sure if I should delete this question or leave it up for other people to see. If someone can reply to this comment to leave it up or delete it would be nice.

Comment: If you intend to leave it up I would suggest creating an answer with more details about the problem and the resolution and marking it accepted, so that others can more easily see if the answer is relevant to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the fluentd image was not seeing the logs was because the data-porter image needs fluentd to finish it's setup so although the data-porter container was running it couldn't properly connect to the fluentd container. In summary any container that needs to connect to fluentd needs to wait for fluentd to finish setting up. 
To fix the issue I had a script that stops the container relying on fluentd and starts it back up. Adding a `container_name: <name>` to the docker-compose.yml file for the services help with the script.

```
docker-compose up -d
sleep(3)
docker stop <container-name-relying-on-fluentd>
docker-compose up -d
```